# Responsive table using flexbox css

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive, css-tables

> I would Like to make a flexible table using flexbox. My goal is to
>   have four items by row and wrap if more than four items I started to
>   implement my solution but I have some issus to make like the image
>   below

[image]

Here is my code :

**CSS**

```
.Rtable {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 // margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;

}
.Rtable-cell {
  //box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;  
  margin: 5px 0 ;
  min-height : 100px;
  display: flex;

     .contrat{
    border: solid 0.6px #6EB6FF;
    width:100%;
    word-break: break-word;

  }

}

.border {
  //border: solid 10px #6EB6FF;
  border-width: thin;
  border-right: 1px solid #6EB6FF;
  border-left: 1px solid #6EB6FF;
  border-top: 1px solid #6EB6FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6EB6FF;
}


/* Table column sizing
================================== */
.Rtable--5cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 20%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Rtable Rtable--5cols">

  <div class="Rtable-cell border">
    <div></div>
    <div class="lienPopin">nom</div>
    <div >lien popin</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Rtable-cell border" >Has a sword named Ice</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell border">No direwolf</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell border"><strong>Lord of Winterfell</strong></div>

  <div class="Rtable-cell border">
    <div></div>
    <div class="lienPopin">nom</div>
    <div >lien popin</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell border">
      <div class="contrats ">
        <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDI - Aide soignant tototoototootoo </h3></div>
        <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDD - Infirmier</h3> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell border">Direwolf: Ghost</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell border"><strong>Knows nothing</strong></div>
```

Comment: There is no image below. This complete guide help me a lote and still does https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/    suggestion: fix your question with some code html and css of the problem and the image or someone will give you down point

Comment: great that how you always have to pos a question. Let me try to give you a good solution

Comment: What you have work already, just change to 4-cols: https://jsfiddle.net/2dk34Lys/

Comment: Ah yeah You right, that work better Thanks a lot @LGSon

Comment: I have some borders big than others one, @LGSon do you know it's possible to make all with the same look ?

Comment: Since one can't collapse borders like one can with `<table>`, you could do like this, where one can set left border to 0 on all but first row item: https://jsfiddle.net/2dk34Lys/1/

Comment: I see thanks @LGSon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html

```
 <div class="Rtable-cell border">
  <div class="contrats ">
    <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDI - Aide soignant tototoototootoo </h3></div>
    <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDD - Infirmier</h3> </div>
</div>
```

My html:

```
 <div class="Rtable-cell border have_inner_item">

                      <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDI - Aide soignant tototoototootoo </h3></div>
                      <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDD - Infirmier</h3> </div>
                      <div class="contrat"> <h3>CDD - other row</h3> </div>

                </div>
```

new css class

```
.have_inner_item {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

}

Is this what your are looking for: Below is the image

Suggestion read this complete guide of [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[image]